# Pandas carve a certain part of a string

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

My data frame contains a column that is mixed numbers and characters.  I want to carve a certain part out of that string.  For instance the string is "Billable at 83% Columbia PK @ st T-362D". I want to carve 83% out from the string.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by carve...

If carve==remove then you can use replace()

```
s = 'Billable at 83% Columbia PK @ st T-362D'

print(s.replace('83%', ''))
# Billable at  Columbia PK @ st T-362D
```

If carve==get then you can use regex, but I'd need additional information to better assist here. Regex allows you to grab part of a string based on its surroundings. You can check out the [regex documentation here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) For example if you were trying to grab the percentage out of the string each time you could do the following.

```
import re

s = 'Billable at 83% Columbia PK @ st T-362D'
match = re.match(r'(\d+%)',s)
print(match.group(1))
# 83%
```

Do either of these answer your question? If not, what do you mean by carve? What would your expected output be?

Comment: By "carve-out", I mean to isolate.  Basically, I just want the numbers in front of the %.  I like your re method.  However, I get an array in each cell rather than a number.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following dataframe:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['L', 'M', 'N'],'B': ["Billable at 73% Columbia PK @ st T-362D", "Billable at 83% Columbia PK @ st T-362D",
                         "Billable at 93% Columbia PK @ st T-362D"]})
```

If we assume by "carve out" you mean to remove, and based on your example "83%" being interpreted as a regular expression, you can use pandas.dataframe.replace() for the column you want to apply changes:

```
df_r = df['B'].replace(to_replace=r'\d+%', value='',regex=True)
df = pd.concat([df.drop(labels="B",axis=1),df_r], axis =1) # replace "B" in original dataframe
```